# Problem: Finding the limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Suppose that a given sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ satisfies the conditions that $x_1=1$ and, for $n\geq 1$,
>   $$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{16}(1+4x_{n}+\sqrt{1+24x_{n}}).$$
>   Determine $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to+\infty} 3x_n.$

I tried writing out the next few terms but I don't see how to do any cancellation. Any small clues? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. If the limit exists and it is finite, say $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to+\infty} x_n=L\in\mathbb{R}$,  then by continuity,
$$16L=1+4L+\sqrt{1+24L}\implies L=?$$
In order to show the convergence consider the increasing function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{16}(1+4x+\sqrt{1+24x})$$ and show that it is a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) in $[f(0),+\infty)=[1/8,+\infty)$ by evaluating its derivative.

P.S. The sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ converges to the unique fixed point $L$ for any $x_1\geq 0$.